# Differences Between Euclid's Axioms and Hibert's Axioms

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I wanted to ask what are the main differences between Euclid's axioms and Hilbert's axioms to geometry? What are the main differences? I understand that Hilbert had more axioms than Euclid, and that they are more accurate, or complete, but what else? Thank you !

Comment: See e.g. the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1245391/why-are-euclid-axioms-of-geometry-considered-not-sound).

Comment: Euclid didn't use all of his axioms. For example "A point has no extent " . And included assumptions that should be axioms. For more on axioms in geometry, see Introduction To Geometry by D. Coxeter (e.g. the sections on Ordered Geometry and Hyperbolic Geonetry) , and Coxeter's introductory textbook on projective geometry.... It has been speculated, on the basis of some vague ancient references, that Euclid may have written, or meant to write, a compendium on 3-D geometry.